# Tiny MCE adding custom HTML tags

Tags: tinymce, modx

I am using Tiny 4.3.3 for MODx
I need to add a

```
<p class="classname">
 <em class="openImg"></em>
  Some randome Input text by the user
 <em class="closeImg"></em>
</p>
```

I don't mind if is an extra menu Item or is in the Paragraph dropdown menu. I just want the less time consuming work around possible.

I have tried this http://alexzag.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/custom-tags-in-tinymce.html but somehow this doesn't work.

Could anyone point me to a good tutorial or tell me how could i add a icon or name to the drop down menu that creates the p and em tags with the right classes automatically please?
Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It has been a while since the question was asked, but as i am currently making exactly the same, i thought i share my discoveries and solutions regarding this matter. :)

I am extending TinyMCE for a test-project at work and our solution needs custom tags - in some of them the user should be able to enter only one line, in others (as your **em**) a lot of text.

Steps to be done, in order to achieve the desired solution:

- tell the TinyMCE editor, that your elements are **good** using the two configuration keywords **extended_valid_elements** and **custom_elements**:

  `tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea#editor",
      // ...
      extended_valid_elements : "emstart,emend",
      custom_elements: "emstart,emend",
      content_css: "editor.css"
   });`
- create the two images for the opening and the closing tag. I named mine for the example *emstart.png* and *emend.png*.
- create a custom CSS style for your custom elements and put them in the custom CSS file (the one that is specified in the TinyMCE configuration, in my case *editor.css*):

  `emstart {
      background: url(emstart.png) no-repeat;
      background-position: left -3px top -3px;
      padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
      background-color:#aabbcc;
      border:1px dotted #CCCCCC;
      height:50px;
      width:100px;
  }`

  `emend {
      background: url(emend.png) no-repeat;
      background-position: left -3px bottom -3px;
      padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
      background-color:#aabbcc;
      border:1px dotted #CCCCCC;
      height:50px;
      width:100px;
  }`
- write a custom plugin that inputs the new tags and put it in the plugins directory. I called mine *customem*:

plugin code:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('customem', function(editor, url) {
    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.addButton('customEmElementButton', {
        text: 'Custom EM',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            // Open window
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Please input text',
                body: [
                    {type: 'textbox', name: 'description', label: 'Text'}
                ],
                onsubmit: function(e) {
                    // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                    editor.insertContent('<emstart>EM Start</emstart><p>' + e.data.description + '</p><emend>EM End</emend>');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Adds a menu item to the tools menu
    editor.addMenuItem('customEmElementMenuItem', {
        text: 'Custom EM Element',
        context: 'tools',
        onclick: function() {
            editor.insertContent('<emstart>EM Start</emstart><p>Example text!</p><emend>EM End</emend>');
        }
    });
});
```

The last step is to load your custom plugin to the editor (using the **plugin** and **toolbar** configuration option) and enjoy the result:

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#editor",
        height: "500px",
        plugins: [
                 "code, preview, contextmenu, image, link, searchreplace, customem"
           ],
        toolbar: "bold italic | example | code | preview | link | searchreplace | customEmElementButton",
        contextmenu: "bold italic",
        extended_valid_elements : "emstart,emend",
        custom_elements: "emstart,emend",
        content_css: "editor.css",
     });
```

The editor now looks like this:

[image]

and the source like in your example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Such a treasure I'm wondering why they don't put such example in the doc...or maybe I've missed it ?

Comment: Glad that the answer helped. At least at the time of writing the answer, I think it was more like understanding the *bigger image* and putting the facts together (and experimenting) - AFAIK there is no such example in the documentation.

Comment: Hello, currently I struggle in implementing custom Vue Components inside the Editor, for example `<swipper :options="optionSet1"></swipper>` it simply removes everything, same for vue directives like `<div v-swipr:swiper="set1"></div>` gets stripped to `<div></div>` any help appreciated you can also invite me into a chat room if you want.

Comment: Hello, I wanted to ask, do you know how to do this for a angular component?
I add in code this `tinymce.init({
      selector: '.page',
      inline: true,
      extended_valid_elements: "app-my-block",
      custom_elements: "app-my-block",
    });`
But tiny doesn't see it as a component.

Comment: @qwerty check if the element is already in the DOM before the init of the tinymce, not that tinymce is initialized, but the element is not present yet. Where / when is the init method if tiny called? is the complete page already loaded/created?

Comment: @keenthinker Great example but after this I have got into another problem. In editor window click on Custom EM button and load the custom elements. Now in editor window our custom element is the very first element. Now move your cursor to the very beginning of the editor window and try to add another elements or simply hit enter. All the newly added elements will render INSIDE of these custom elements but as we moved our cursor before custom elements so these newly added elements should render before and out side of custom elements.

Comment: @keenthinker below is question with more details regarding above explained scenario:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66219539/pressing-enter-key-is-adding-br-tags-inside-custom-tag-instead-of-outside-in-t

Answer (score 5):

First of all you will need to modify the tinymce setting [`valid_elements`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements) and [`valid_children`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_children) to your needs (add `em` to the `valid_elements` and `em` as child to the tags desired (probably `p`) to `valid_children`).

Second you will need an own plugin with an own drop down or button to insert this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one or more tag structures simply using the template plugin.

See documentation
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/template/

See interactive example:
https://codepen.io/gpsblues/pen/WNdLgvb

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#template',
  height: 300,
  plugins: 'template code',
  menubar: 'insert',
  toolbar: 'template code',
  extended_valid_elements: "emstart[*],emend[*]",
  templates : [
    {
      title: 'emstart/emend',
      description: 'Add a personal tag structure with personal tags <emstart></emstart> <emend></emend>.',
      content: '<p class="classname"><emstart class="openImg"></emstart>Input text<emend class="closeImg"></emend></p>'
    }
  ],
  content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px}'
});
```