# JS function to remove tag

Tags: javascript, button, tags, tinymce

I have added a button to TinyMCE using the following JS code:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('button_span', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton('button_span', {
            text: 'Test Button',
            icon: false,
            onclick : function() {
                editor.selection.setContent('<em>' + editor.selection.getContent() + '</em>');

            }
        });
    });
})();
```

So, when user clicks the button, it wraps any highlighted words into `<em>` tags.

My question is, how do I make it so that if the highlighted words are already in `<em>` tag, then it should **remove** the tag. I am guessing we need to adjust the onclick function.

Comment: Doesn't TinyMCE already have that functionality?

Comment: You mean an *em* tag? Yes it does. I just added it as an example to simplify the question.

Comment: My point is that the same functionality exists in the core, abstracted to handle any number of tags. Doesn't that provide a suitable example?

Comment: cant you just save editor.selection.getContent() into a variable and check to see if it contains '<em>'? then remove it if yes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tiny MCE adding custom HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407190/tiny-mce-adding-custom-html-tags)

Comment: @Bradley Can you show me how?

Comment: @isherwood The answer you linked to does not outline how the tag is removed which is the core of my question. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Isn't that what any button does if a tag is already in place? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @isherwood No it doesn't unfortunately, which is why I am confused why this was marked as duplicate.

Comment: What doesn't? If I select text using TinyMCE and click the [I] button (or [B] or whatever), first it adds an `<em>` tag. If I click again, it removes it. Is this not exactly the functionality you're asking for?

Comment: @isherwood It doesn't with my custom botton. It adds the tag, BUT doesn't remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give this a shot. I'm not very familiar with tinyMCE but this should work in general. Also, you'll want to expand this to check to see if there is also an '', and the replaces will vary based on that, this is just to get you started, but like I said, should be the basis of what your trying to do I think.

```
onclick : function() {
    var contents = editor.selection.getContent();
    if (contents.indexOf('<em>') >= 0) {
        contents.replace('<em>', '');
        contents.replace('</em>', '');
        editor.selection.setContent(contents);
    } else {
        editor.selection.setContent('<em>' + editor.selection.getContent() + '</em>');
    }
}
```