# How to allow some custom tag in tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-3

when i pest a html code inside tinymce editor my **< figure>** tag remove by this editor.

how to allow this tag in tinymce editor.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="list-top">
        <figure>1</figure>
        <div class="list-top-right">
            <h3>It's Competitive Out There</h3>
        </div>
    </div>      
</li>
</ul>
```

it convert into

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="list-top">
        1
        <div class="list-top-right">
            <h3>It's Competitive Out There</h3>
        </div>
    </div>      
</li>
</ul>
```

Just remove this `<figure>1</figure>` tag

Comment: This works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407190/tiny-mce-adding-custom-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` in jquery

```
$("ul li").html(function(i,h){ 
         return h.replace(/<figure>/g,'').replace(/<\/figure>/g,'');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nk0nLLgv/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell TinyMCE to treat `figure` as valid element.

Use this option: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:extended_valid_elements