# Sometimes allow <html> in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

How can I configure TinyMCE so that it allows tags such as `<!doctype>`, `<html>`, and `<body>` but does not force them to be present? Sometimes I would like to enter the full page of HTML and sometimes I only want to enter HTML that exists inside a body.

By default, TinyMCE expects content in the editor to be within a `<p>` tag and strips off any tags such as `<!doctype>`.

So, if I enter

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Some text</body>
</html>
```

the result from TinyMCE is `Some text`.

I've found I can include these elements if I use the [fullpage plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/fullpage/). But this plugin *forces* the surrounding tags.

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI Thanks for the reference but solutions to that problem do not fix this one. Removing the root block element does not allow the additional `<html>` etc tags to be added.

Comment: ah I thought you had a solution for it but you get <p>s inserted as well. deleted my first answer. does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27265867/614277

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI No, the `valid_elements` option only applies to elements placeable within a `<p>` tag.

Comment: couldn't you just add the surrounding html-tags to your content after editing?

Comment: @Thariama Unfortunately I'm using a third-party tool with limited customization so I cannot add the html tags by code.