# Why are Custom Elements Breaking TinyMCE in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

## Background

I am working on extending the visual editor inside WordPress, which is just TinyMCE:

[image]

I am using a structure of:

```
<section>
    <controls></controls>
    <content>
        <column class="one-third">
        </column>
        <column class="two-thirds">
        </column>
    </content>
</section>
```

## Problem

The problem is that when I try to change text from `Paragraph` to `Header`, nothing happens:

[image]

## Problem Cause

I've tracked the issue down to using custom elements. When I change my code to use this structure, the problem goes away:

```
<section>
    <controls></controls>
    <article>
        <div class="one-third">
        </div>
        <div class="two-thirds">
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

## Attempted Solutions

I have tried adding `column` and `content` to the `extended_valid_elements` and the `custom_elements` lists, and that has had zero effect.

```
$init['custom_elements'] = 'content[*],column[*]';
$init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'content[*],column[*]';
```

## Question

Is there anything that pops out immediately that I'm doing completely wrong? Is there a way to get around this, or to force TinyMCE to treat my custom elements as valid?

Comment: What version of the TinyMCE editor is being used by Wordpress? I remember having lots of problems with 2 that got fixed with an upgrade to 3, like problems that just didn't have a solution.

Comment: 4.x. Not sure which exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

In the `custom_elements` declaration, you used `content[*], column[*]` instead of `content, column`. While the `extended_valid_elements` does require the attributes to be declared, `custom_elements` doesn't.

Per the TinyMCE docs: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#custom_elements

### Solution:

Change this:

```
$init['custom_elements'] = 'content[*],column[*]';
$init['extended_valid_elements'] = 'content[*],column[*]';
```

To this:

```
$init['custom_elements'] = 'content,column';
```

## Edit

Please note, it is critical that there are no spaces included in the comma-delimited lists.

`'content,column';`  <--- works.

`'content, column';` <--- **doesn't work.**

Comment: dang. would this solution work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407190/tiny-mce-adding-custom-html-tags

Comment: In your original answer, you suggested both no attributes, and explicit attributes. I only tried the latter. Removing the attributes entirely was the solution though. I've updated your answer for clarity and marked it as solution. Much appreciated.