# Tinymce custom tag passing attributes

Tags: angular, tinymce, custom-tags

i have created a custom tag in tinymce. In that custom tag i want to pass name. so this is the code i tried

```
<field name="field">textbox</field>
```

Here if i get the final source generate by tinymce it has only

```
<field>textbox</field>
```

in the source data.
I want to get the whole thing with the name as well in the source.

I refered this to make the custom tag [Tiny MCE adding custom HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407190/tiny-mce-adding-custom-html-tags).

Comment: not clear with your requirement, can you please elaborate it more

Comment: ok i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

You can use an option to declare new valid elements and their attributes like:

```
tinymce.init({
    extended_valid_elements: 'field[name]'
});
```

you can play with this option like these possibilities:

```
extended_valid_elements: 'img[class=myclass|!src|border:0|alt|title|width|height|style]'
```