# Create Custom Tags for TinyMce or Filter Input?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, text-editor

I don't have a specific technical question, but was hoping to get some thoughts on two different approaches that I am considering. I am trying to build custom shorthand tags for the TinyMCE editor, and most of the tutorials online go the route of creating a custom plugin for the TinyMCE editor, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407190/tiny-mce-adding-custom-html-tags).

When I originally thought about this problem, I didn't think it would be necessary to do this, but rather create a JS script that filtered through the users input and more-or-less did a 'find and replace' - looking for tags and replacing them with whatever.

I think the second approach would be easier and less complicated, but I was just hoping to get some thoughts before I started working on this tomorrow.